# CAKE PHP 1.1 and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in cakePHP .
and we are using Cake PHP 1.1

I have a problem regarding the attachment of the Javascript in my page.

This is the model..

```
class information extends AppModel{
    //name of the table in database
    var $name = 'informations';

}
```

This is the Controller ..

```
class InformationController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'information';

    function index(){
    }
}
```

And this is the view

```
<div class= "span12">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active">
            <a class="menu-bar" href="#">User Management</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-bar" href="#">View All</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu-bar" href="#">Modify User</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu-bar" href="#">Delete User</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu-bar" href="#">Manage User</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active"> <img src="/img/png/24x24/accept.png"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="/img/png/24x24/delete.png"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="/img/png/24x24/accept.png"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

How can i attach here my Js .. 
js/bootstrap-carousel.js

Help me please ..
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why would you use CakePHP 1.1 ?

Comment: @pudelhund Because this is the framework being used by the company

Comment: Update - to 1.3 at least. For the sake of everyone :)

Comment: Our Boss! Don't want to upgrade , I don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout file and add it in the HTML of the layout like you would in a normal HTML page.

http://book.cakephp.org/1.1/en/views.html#layouts

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably read the CakePHP "cookbook".
Following conventions is ESSENTIAL in Cake. You should begin your model with a capital letter. And your controller should be "MODELNAME + s + Controller", resulting in "InformationsController", for your example.

Everything you need to access on every page (i.e. a navigation) can be added to a Layout view - there should already be a standard layout here, so you may see how this works:

`app -> View -> Layouts -> default.ctp`

Adding the script here would make it accessible it to ALL your view files.

If instead you just need to access it on a single view page you should simply implement the script there, using `<script>`Tags, as you would in the layout view.
You could also use CakePHP's [JavascriptHelper Class](http://api11.cakephp.org/class_javascript_helper.html#8d73949172d3352883cefc6f76ec1e77) to do that.

Finally, as [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark) suggested in the comments, you should at least (!) update to 1.3